# Wso2 Api Manager - OAuth Token Error- OAuth application is not in active state

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I was trying to test publisher apis documented here "[RESTful API for WSO2 API Manager - Publisher](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide)"

To execute any api i need a admin access toke. To generate that, it is advised to run following command :

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=apim:api_view" -H "Authorization: Basic SGZFbDFqSlBkZzV0YnRyeGhBd3liTjA1UUdvYTpsNmMwYW9MY1dSM2Z3ZXpIaGM3WG9HT2h0NUFh" https://127.0.0.1:8243/token
```

I replaced basic authorization with admin and password of admin user. I got following error when i attempted to execute it:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_client",
  "error_description": "Oauth application is not in active state."
}    
Status Code : 401 Unauthorized
```

please advise what is wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Authorization header should contain the base64 encoded value of clientId:secret

You should first obtain clientId and secret with curl command [1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide) and then execute [2]

[1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide) `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic base64(username:password)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d <payload> http://localhost:9763/client-registration/v0.11/register`

A sample json  is found in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide) document.

[2] `curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&scope=apim:api_view" -H "Authorization: Basic base64(clientId:secret)" https://127.0.0.1:8243/token`

Comment: Thank  you! i was thinking step1 and 2 are separate activities. Thanks for help. Its working now for me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the accepted answer, it led me to check the encoding of the client id and secret that I had copied from another app.

**Solution:**

Though I couldn't visually see the difference, `I copied the client id and secret directly from ws02 and pasted into postman auth and that fixed it.`

Even though the characters were the same the above solution worked. It leads me to believe one or more of the characters were encoded in the wrong character encoding or I had an invisible character in there. Another developer also had this same issue with copy/paste.